# Python script not executing properly from Php

Tags: php, python, server, automation

I'm trying to run a python script with Php but it's not running properly when I launch it with Php. This script, here "bot.py" interracts with the instagram api and writes the output as a text file in 'bot1.txt'.

Here is the Php code :

```html
shell_exec("python automation/bot.py");
```

And here is the python snippet that writes in the file :

```
with open('../botlog/bot1.txt', 'a') as the_file:
                    the_file.write('Followed')
```

My problem is that when I launch it with Php the script runs but doesn't write in the file bot1.txt. When I run the python script with the command line everything works perfectly so I don't understand what's the deal here.
I'm working with MAMP on a local server.
Thank you !

Comment: What are the file permissions for bot1.txt? Which user/group does it belong to?

Comment: 33279 it's written

Comment: From the command line run `ls -l path/to/bot1.txt` You should get a response like this `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114 Nov 13 19:43 bot1.txt`

Comment: @miknik -rwxrwxrwx  1 nicolas  admin  0 30 nov 15:40 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lepetitrobotPYTHON/automated/botlog/bot1.txt

Comment: Use the [edit] button to draw attention to your new findings (yes, incorporate the comments, and any debugging steps) - rather than reposting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should specify your path to php.

```
$myPHPScriptPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then specify the relative path to your python script.

Hope it helps